wp event manager- stripe split pay issue connecting
I'm having issues with stripe split pay.
the website is a hub for organisers to come and post their events and sell tickets. the platform will take a percentage of the ticket sale and the rest will go to the event organiser. this was the main reason I bought the All Events Manager Pro.
Currently
-im getting a blank screen for the connect stripe as the organiser

it should look like this:

-and the 'you are not allowed' as you are an admin as admin which is expected

I am working in test mode and the stripe is connected.  All the payment comes to my stripe account minus the stripe fees.
but they do not go to the organiser as there is no way to connect to the plaform.

I made a ticket and got a responce saying to "reinstall the wp event manager" but that would delete a lot of work....
please help me find a solution.
Many thanks
some resources from the themes website:
https://wp-eventmanager.com/knowledge-base/stripe-split-payment/#articleTOC_1
https://wp-eventmanager.com/set-up-stripe-wordpress/?srsltid=AfmBOopgkljGaAD5_1XUB73Cbd3HL06MynTiexOn8dMRzCNg4usoUAp7
